# Codeigniter: 404 on calling controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Accessing Url-http://localhost:82/admin/login
Then-
I am getting 404 "Page not found error" 
 i.e-

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.27

My config.php

```html
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:82/admin';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
| 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
| 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
|
| WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

My routes.php

```html
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
//$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


/*admin*/
//$route['admin'] = 'user/index';
//$route['admin/signup'] = 'user/signup';
//$route['admin/create_member'] = 'user/create_member';
$route['admin'] = 'admin';
//$route['admin/logout'] = 'admin/logout';


$route['package'] = 'package';
```

My controller Admin.php

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

 /**
  * Index Page for this controller.
  *
  * Maps to the following URL
  *   http://example.com/index.php/admin
  * - or -
  *   http://example.com/index.php/admin/index
  * - or -
  * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
  * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
  *
  * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
  * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
  * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
  */
       function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('LoginModel');
       $this->load->library('session');
    }
      
      
    
 public function index()
 {
            if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
   redirect('package/packages');
        }else{
         $this->load->view('admin/admin'); 
        }
  
 }
          function __encrip_password($password) {
        return md5($password);
    } 
         /**
    * check the username and the password with the database
    * @return void
    */
        public function login()
 { 
      echo "hi"; exit;
  

  $user_name = $this->input->post('username');
  $password = $this->__encrip_password($this->input->post('password'));

  $is_valid = $this->LoginModel->validate($user_name, $password);
  
  if($is_valid)
  {
   $data = array(
    'user_name' => $user_name,
    'is_logged_in' => true
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
   redirect('package/package');
  }
  else // incorrect username or password
  {
   $data['message_error'] = TRUE;
   $this->load->view('admin/admin', $data); 
  }
 }
        
       

   
 
  

    /**
    * The method just loads the signup view
    * @return void
    */
}
```

Comment: show your controller code & URL trying to access

Comment: I added the url in question

Comment: What version of CI

Comment: Is your admin file name Admin.php first letter upper case

Comment: In your base url end it with forward slash `/` like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:82/yourprojectname/';`

Comment: Yes first letter upper case

Comment: @ wolfgang1983 -not end with forward slash

Comment: Not end with forward slash

Answer (score 0):

May be you have .htaccess as your controller seems fine and still you are getting this answer. please try to add .htaccess in your root directory.

Answer (score 0):

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin/index';
```

guess it should be ?

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
```